# perl print file last modifed time

Tags: perl

I have used the following method to print the file last modified time but the result the time printed on script has 2 hrs backward than the file stamp.

```
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;

$file = '/opt/test/time';
$date = ctime(stat($file)->mtime);
print "<b> $date </b>";
```

the time stamp on file name "test" is 12:30 pm but the script time display as 10:30 am.

did i miss anything?

Comment: Possibly a timezone correction is being done somewhere.  Your system might be storing the mtime in GMT and then the script is converting it, or vice versa.

Comment: Check the value of the TZ env var in the shell.  Is it what you expect?

Comment: there is a time zone difference between the remote file and my server that is PDT and MDT which is 1 hour, but not sure why I have 2 hours difference.

Comment: What do you call "file stamp" (i.e. how do you get that value)?

Comment: Also, you didn't answer  martin clayton's question.

Comment: ZONE="America/Los_Angeles"
UTC=false
ARC=false                                                                                                                                    I think the daylight saving as @choroba" said add another one hour.

Comment: Why not print both your local and the UTC time.  For the 'mtime' use: `perl -e 'print scalar gmtime ((stat("$ARGV[0]"))[9]),"\n"' myfile` Substitute `localtime` for `gmtime` for your TZ.